# Matplotlib: Multiple legends on same figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, legend

I have a few plot functions that each receive different kinds of data and plot them, with their own title and legends. However, when I try to plot them on the same figure, the former one is overwritten.

I understand that one way to do this is to call `get_artist()`, however since the legends are created inside functions, this doesn't seem possible. Is there any type of `LegendHandler` to do this? To retrieve the legend from each plot and show them on the figure? Should I return the legend from each function?

Here is a simplified code of what I have:

```
def plot_1(fig, data, ax = None):
    if ax = None:
        ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.plot(data)
    ax.set_xlabel('t')
    plt.axis('tight')

    # Create a legend
    colors = {'A':'blue',
              'B':'yellow',
              'C':'red'}
    legend_labels = []
    legend_handles = []

    for key in colors.keys():
        legend_labels.append(key)
        p = matplotlib.patches.Rectangle((0, 0), 1, 1, fc = colors[key], alpha = 0.5)
        legend_handles.append(p)
    ax.legend(legend_handles, legend_labels, loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))

def plot_2(fig, data, ax = None):
    if ax = None:
        ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.plot(data, color='green', linewidth=1, label='L1')
    ax.set_xlabel('t')
    ax.autoscale()
    ax.legend()

def main():

    plot_1(fig, data = data1)
    plot_2(fig, data = data2)
```

I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it, but since I am using these plotting models multiple times, I feel that I have to keep them in function forms as they are.

#### Note from comment:

- [matplotlib: 2 different legends on same graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12761806) is the reason I mentioned `get_artist`, which was mentioned in that thread. I have actually solved it using that for now, but I was looking for a cleaner way for this particular case. What I have done for now is to return a `legend` from each function and do what was suggested in that thread.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [matplotlib: 2 different legends on same graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12761806/matplotlib-2-different-legends-on-same-graph)

Answer (score 0):

Make your functions return the legend

```
def plot_2(fig, data, ax = None):
    ....
    return ax.legend()
```

Then you can do

```
legend1 = plot_1(fig, data = data1)
plot_2(fig, data = data2)
pyplot.gca().add_artist(legend1)
```

As suggested here: [matplotlib: 2 different legends on same graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12761806/matplotlib-2-different-legends-on-same-graph)

Comment: Thank you. That's actually what I have mentioned in the comment above, but I was looking for a more "pythonic" way if there exists any.

Comment: Probably there is if you do not use the pyplot interface, but look into the object-oriented interface of matplotlib.

Answer (score 0):

> I have actually solved it using that [`add_artist`] for now, but I was looking for a cleaner way

There is no cleaner way.

Each Axes object (each subplot) maintains a `.legend_` attribute, that is initially set to `None` and later is **destructively** updated each time `ax.legend(...)` or `plt.legend(...)` is used.

Your only choice is to label (give a name to) the first legend Artist, and when it's removed from the Axes namespace. i.e,, from `ax.legend_` you MUST place it into the Axes again, using `ax.add_artist(...)`.

Re WHY Matplotlib is designed like this, I'd ask MATLAB designers but I may be wrong :-)