# Laying 2 different legends in one axis in matplotlib's gridspec module

Tags: matplotlib, plot

I'm now working on a plot using matplotlib's `gridspec` module. I want to add 2 different legends on an specific axis, like the one mentioned in [matplotlib: 2 different legends on same graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12761806/matplotlib-2-different-legends-on-same-graph).

However, with `gridspec`, I always get one legend laid on other axis and one lost.

Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

fig = plt.figure()
gs1 = gridspec.GridSpec(8, 4)
gs1.update(left=0.1, right=0.65, bottom=0.06, top=1, hspace=0)

axF = plt.subplot(gs1[0, :])
axE = plt.subplot(gs1[1, :],sharex=axF)
axPA = plt.subplot(gs1[2, :],sharex=axF)
axMiu = plt.subplot(gs1[3:7, :],sharex=axF)
axRes = plt.subplot(gs1[7, :],sharex=axF)

hd1=axMiu.errorbar(range(5),map(lambda x:x+1,range(5)), fmt='o',     color='black', mfc='none',markersize=5, label='hehe')
hd2=axMiu.errorbar(range(5),map(lambda x:x+2,range(5)), fmt='-',         color='fuchsia',markersize=5, linewidth=2, label='heihei')

first_legend=plt.legend(prop={'size':12},labelspacing=0,handles=[hd2],loc='upper right')
axMiu.add_artist(first_legend)
plt.legend(prop={'size':12},labelspacing=0,handles=[hd1],loc='right')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 5):

you need to use `axis.legend`, not `plt.legend`.

For example, make your final 4 lines:

```
first_legend=axMiu.legend(prop={'size':12},labelspacing=0,handles=[hd2],loc='upper right')
axMiu.add_artist(first_legend)
axMiu.legend(prop={'size':12},labelspacing=0,handles=[hd1],loc='right')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's just what I want!