# How to generate two legends for a scatterplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I want to generate two different legends for these five points according to their size, the corresponding labels are written in my code, but I only generate one wrong legend so far, how can I correct my code?
By the way, if I want to generate wiring with the same logic as in my code, is there a better way? I have checked a lot of information and can only generate the picture like this, I hope to get your help to optimize the code. Thanks in advance!

Edit:
I made changes with reference to [matplotlib: 2 different legends on same graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12761806/matplotlib-2-different-legends-on-same-graph), but the legend I got is still incorrect. I want to add legends only with dots instead of lines. I also tried some methods but all failed, can you give me some suggestions？

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X_new = np.random.randint(1,20,(3,2))
x1 = X_new[0,:]
x2 = X_new[1,:]
x3 = X_new[2,:]

p = np.random.randint(1,20,(1,2))
p1 = np.random.randint(1,20,(1,2))


# plt.style.use('ggplot')
color_map = {0: 'blue', 1:'green', 2: 'darkred', 3: 'black', 4:'red'}
legend1_label = {0: 'trn1', 1: 'trn2', 2: 'trn3'}
legend2_label = {0: 'p', 1: 'p1'}

plt.plot()

for idx, cl in enumerate(legend1_label):
    scatter = plt.scatter(x=X_new[idx, 0], y=X_new[idx, 1], c=color_map[cl], marker='.',
                s=100)
plt.plot([x1[0],p[0,0]], [x1[1],p[0,1]], color='k',linestyle='--',linewidth=1)
plt.plot([x2[0],p[0,0]], [x2[1],p[0,1]], color='k',linestyle='--',linewidth=1)
plt.plot([x3[0],p[0,0]], [x3[1],p[0,1]], color='k',linestyle='--',linewidth=1)
plt.plot([x1[0],p1[0,0]], [x1[1],p1[0,1]], color='r',linestyle='--',linewidth=1)
plt.plot([x2[0],p1[0,0]], [x2[1],p1[0,1]], color='r',linestyle='--',linewidth=1)
plt.plot([x3[0],p1[0,0]], [x3[1],p1[0,1]], color='r',linestyle='--',linewidth=1)
plt.scatter(x=p[0,0], y=p[0,1],c='red',marker='.',s=200)  
plt.scatter(x=p1[0,0], y=p1[0,1],c='black',marker='.',s=200)


legend1 = plt.legend(labels=["trn1","trn2","trn3"],loc=4, title="legend1")
plt.legend(labels=["p","p1"], title="legend2")
plt.gca().add_artist(legend1)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: You may have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12761806/matplotlib-2-different-legends-on-same-graph

Comment: I made changes with reference to the link you gave, but the legend I got is still incorrect. I want to add legends only with dots instead of lines. I also tried some methods but all failed, can you give me some Suggestions?